# CountIf Index Match mark unique

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Above is an example in Column F i have a data set that potentialy contains duplicate values (highlighted green), on the corresponding row in column G it notes whether that value is a "Col" or a "Del" In column H is where i want the result, the result being;

If there is more than one instance in column F and the corresponding value in Column G contains 'Col' and a 'Del' then mark the first record with a 'Y' else leave blank.

I'm trying to find how may times we made both a delivery and collection from the same site and not just a delivery or a collection.

Many thanks

Comment: Markdown sample data would be very usefull for people here to re-create the issue. Also, please edit your question to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yes, some expected results would be nice.

Comment: @OverflowStacker Thank you, i made reference to my expected result to be in Column H, apologies if i did not make this clear.

Comment: @JvdV I have tried to follow some examples that you kindly provided to me in a previous post, i'm sorry that my skill set is just not good enough to understand or indeed strip and test, which i have tried for hours. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you question correctly, you can use this

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,$A2)>1,COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A2)<1),"Y","")
```

[image]

just if there are multiple occurances of an item or:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,$A2)>1,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,"col")>0,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,"del")>0,COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A2)<1),"Y","")
```

[image]

for the first occurence of a site with at least one delivery and collection.

**UPDATE**
In the second formula the first `COUNTIF` is not necessary as this condition is also checked by the next two `COUNTIFS`.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,"col")>0,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,"del")>0,COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A2)<1),"Y","")
```

The first `COUNTIFS` counts the number of collections at the current site, the second `COUNTIFS` is for delivery. The last `COUNTIF` expands, when you pull it down. It gives a `FALSE`, if the current site was already above in the list.

Comment: That is exactly what i need, thank you so much, i am now going to take long hard look at what exactly the formula is doing :0)

Comment: @Prospidnick see UPDATE for a shorter formula and some explanation

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the following option::

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(SUM(--(A2=$A$2:$A$16)*--("C"=$B$2:$B$16))>=1)
+--(SUM((--(A2=$A$2:$A$16)*--("D"=$B$2:$B$16)))>=1))
*--(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1)>1,"Y","")
```

[image]